# Bootstrap independent scrolling for 3 column design

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 column design similar to answers.yahoo.com and i need to add similar scrolling feature which i tried but it is not working for some reason

Fiddle: [fiddle.jshell.net/DTcHh/5821/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DTcHh/5821/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-2" style="padding:0 5px!important;">
            <div class="c-scroll" style="background-color:#333; width:100%; min-height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                <p>This is category bar</p>
                 <p>Question 1</p>
                 <p>Question 2</p>
                 <p>Question 3</p>
                 <p>Question 4</p>
                 <p>Question 5</p>
                 <p>Question 6</p>
                 <p>Question 7</p>
                 <p>Question 8</p>
                 <p>Question 9</p>
                 <p>Question 10</p>
                 <p>Question 11</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-pull-8" style="height:auto; padding:0 5px!important;">
            <div style="background-color:#333; width:100%; min-height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                <p>Featured Question</p>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:#333;width:100%; min-height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                <p>Top Question</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="min-height:200px; padding:0 5px!important;">
            <div style="background-color:#333; width:100%; min-height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                <p>right column</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use boostrap column class sm or xs for small screen like md:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-md-push-2 col-sm-push-2" style="padding:0 5px!important;">
                <div class="c-scroll" style="background-color:#333; width:100%; min-height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <p>This is category bar</p>
                     <p>Question 1</p>
                     <p>Question 2</p>
                     <p>Question 3</p>
                     <p>Question 4</p>
                     <p>Question 5</p>
                     <p>Question 6</p>
                     <p>Question 7</p>
                     <p>Question 8</p>
                     <p>Question 9</p>
                     <p>Question 10</p>
                     <p>Question 11</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-md-pull-8 col-sm-pull-8" style="height:auto; padding:0 5px!important;">
                <div style="background-color:#333; width:100%; min-height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <p>Featured Question</p>
                </div>
                <div style="background-color:#333;width:100%; min-height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <p>Top Question</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="min-height:200px; padding:0 5px!important;">
                <div style="background-color:#333; width:100%; min-height:200px; margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <p>right column</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i had deliberately used `md` so that it can cover large tablets also only issue i have about independent scrolling which doesn't work i have to make it work with `md` otherwise left column will be too narrow on small screen which i don't want

Comment: Event if i follow you design still middle column doesn't scale to 100%

Comment: add 100% column col-md-12 sm-12 etc